# Will I have problems in future applications if my Schengen visa doesn't have an exit stamp?

Tags: visas, schengen

I lost my passport in which I had a Spanish student visa. After I replaced my passport, I got a Czech Schengen visa, valid for 10 days. When I  finished the semester in Spain, I left the Schengen area but they didn’t stamp my passport because there was no Spanish visa in it, and the other visa was already expired. In the future, when I want to apply for a Schengen visa, is this going to be a problem when there's a visa without an exit stamp?

Comment: Many countries don't stamp passports on exit nowadays, especially for residency permit holders. Your departure has been recorded in the database, do no worries.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk: Schengen countries do (or must) stamp passport of all exiting travelers, except passports issued by EU/EEA countries (and passports of travelers holding family residence permits).

Comment: They're quite bad at stamping at certain land borders, however, so it is quite possible to end up lacking an exit stamp.

Comment: @HenningMakholm National practice varies between countries, however, plus some countries have lazy officers. In France, for example, the policy is to stamp residence permit holders, but many officers are lazy to (which is illegal on their part). Germany and Switzerland are diligent about stamping in general, but the policy is **not** to stamp residence permit holders

Comment: You may be asked to prove you left before your visa expires. Save copies of air tickets just in case.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sweden does not: just verified with 2 of my friends who are non-EU citizens and have residency here (one is a student)

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk there is no comprehensive database of Schengen entries and exits.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Some countries do record for their own records though, Spain being one of them. So if re-entering through Spain OP would be fine

Comment: Hmm, if so they are in direct violation of the [borders code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407) whose Article 11 explicitly (and presumbly exhaustively) list which groups of third-country nationals should _not_ get stamps.

Comment: In my case, the visa was a tourist visa for 10 days so it would be obvious that I didn’t have a reaidance permit. I think they would think that I didn’t exit legaly outside schengen? :/

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not have problems just because of that. Based on personal experience Spain border guards are quite lax on stamping passports (in violation of Schengen Borders Code, BTW), and their embassies know that.

Hold on your boarding pass and the evidence of your presence outside the Schengen area (some receipts etc), and present it to the embassy if you are challenged. Schengen embassies generally follow up with you if some extra paperwork is needed (again based on personal experience).